# show iphone addressbook contacts in wi-fi localhost using ip address in browser ios

Tags: ios, browser, abaddressbook

In my iOS app i'm trying to show my `iphone` contacts in browser and download through it

I'm getting ipaddress but how to show contacts in browser when i enter *ipaddress* in browser

Comment: That's likely to be impossible. I don't think the iPhone has an API to expose internal data through http.

Comment: i'm finding this type of activity in "Aircontacts" and "MyContactBackup" apps but not founding any where in googling